# Grails 2.3.x: How to get plugin name when running plugin by itself?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

In my Grails 2.3.5 **plugin descriptor file**, I'm trying to grab the plugin name or app name, depending on whether its running as a normal Grails app or if the plugin is being run by itself. Its the latter I'm having trouble with.

I've tried the following inside the  `doWithSpring` closure:

```
application.metadata.getApplicationName()
application.metadata['app.name']
appName
application.config.appName
this.plugin.name
```

all of which are either null or an empty Map.

I have a feeling I have to somehow access the current [`GrailsPlugin`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/GrailsPlugin.html) or [`GrailsPluginUtils`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/GrailsPluginUtils.html) but I haven't made any progress there.

Comment: *running plugin by itself* - What does it mean?

Comment: cd myGrailsPlugin; grails run-app

Comment: got it. Should be using a container like tomcat? make sure it is not exported with the plugin.

Comment: Agreed, will only ever be called when being used for `dev` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this in plugin descriptor.

```
import grails.util.Holders

....

def doWithSpring = {
    //gives plugin name while using through app
    def appName = manager.getGrailsPluginForClassName(this.class.simpleName).name

    //gives plugin project name
    def name = Holders.config.grails.plugin.myplugin.name
}
```

Changes in `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.myplugin.name=appName
```

This config entry should not pollute when the plugin is used through the app. You would get an empty map for `name` above when plugin is run through the app.

Comment: This does give me the appName but in the wrong format. It returns the camelCase version (myPlugin) but I actually need the project name, which is what you see for the context path, when you use `grails run-app` in the console. E.g. `Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/my-plugin/`.

Comment: In `Config.groovy`, `appName` is still `null`. Also, maybe I've missed something but those edits seem to rely on hard-coding the value `myplugin`. I may as well simply hard-code the string value (`my-plugin`) where I need it in the plugin descriptor in this case. My original use case was to be able to detect the name so that if the plugin was renamed, then the code would continue to work.

Comment: There is no hard coding involved. `appName` in Config.groovy will actually read `application.properties` file from the plugin and get the plugin name. I could have answered the easiest way by saying hard code the name, but this is fully dynamic. It works for me. I chose the config property arbitrarily.

Comment: `app.name` was missing from my `application.properties` files - as recommended by http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1973 - "delete everything from application.properties except the app.grails.version property". Thus I couldn't test your `grails.plugin.myplugin.name=appName`, so I was assuming `myplugin` was a card-coded string for the current project, not a variable that grabs the current plugin. Yes it now works, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

@dmahapatro's answer got me to the desired outcome so I marked his answer as correct.

But the underlying problem I encountered was actually due to a missing attribute in `application.properties` - `app.name`. So I've extracted the relevant information from the comments and put them in this answer for future reference.

I converted a Grails app to a plugin using the very useful directions from Burt Beckwith on [Converting Grails Applications to Plugins and vice versa](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1973). In it he suggests:

> delete everything from application.properties except the
>   app.grails.version property

This is the reason why my original attempt with `application.metadata.getApplicationName()` returned null.

**Adding `app.name` back into `application.properties`, fixed this so that `application.metadata.getApplicationName()` gave me the value I needed.**

Someone else pointed out this omission in the comments to the blog but Burt has not updated his article or replied to the comment, so I cannot categorically say you should add `app.name` to every plugin, only that it worked for me in this instance (YMMV).